# Jquery play and stop button

Tags: jquery, jplayer

Im hoping to get some help with this custom jplayer mp3 im trying to put on my blog (blogger platform). Im basically an amature in every meaning of the word when it comes to coding. I followed this tutorial from [here](http://karolo.com/blog/developer/jplayer-how-to-use-jplayer-to-build-your-own-mp3-player.html) and did everthing on point but I still cant get the player to work. Here's the code. Any help will be GREATLY appreciated cause ive been tying to do this thing for days.

```
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
    // Using jQuery object, rather than $
    var mediaPlayer = jQuery('#mediaContainer');
```

`mediaPlayer.jPlayer({
    // Tells JPlayer where to find the SWF file.
    swfPath: 'https://sites.google.com/site/maestromuzic/Jplayer.swf',

    // Fix for some older Andriod phones.
    solution:    "flash, html",

    // Tells the player that the track is available in:
    //         mp3, Ogg Vorbis and Wave formats.
    supplied : 'mp3',

    // Assigns the CSS selectors which will control the player,
    //         creating buttons.
    cssSelector: {
        play: '#playButton',
        pause: '#pauseButton',
        stop: '#stopButton'
    },

    // Assigns the files for each format, once the player is loaded.
    ready: function() {jQuery(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
        mp3: 'http://files.mboxdrive.com/1296462407/Lutan Fyah - Badmind.mp3',
    });}

});
$('#playButton').click(function() {
    $('#mediaContainer').jPlayer('play');
});
$('#pauseButton').click(function() {
    $('#mediaContainer').jPlayer('pause');
});
$('#stopButton').click(function() {
    $('#mediaContainer').jPlayer('stop');
 });
 });
</script> 


 <div id="mediaPlayer">
 <div id="mediaContainer">
 </div>
 <div id="playButton">
 Play</div>
 <div id="pauseButton">
 Pause</div>
 <div id="stopButton">
 Stop</div>
 </div><code>`

Comment: Try removing the line `solution:    "flash, html",` and the event handlers at the bottom.

Comment: thanx for yuh reply but no luck still. If anyone can help id greatly appreciate this man. I dont even mind paying if someone wants to sort it out for me. Anybody?

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to identify the problem without seeing where you put the player and the assoiated code. However, I did create a test version mp3 using the official site for JPlayer and also had problems. I am assuming it has to do with JPlayer's server side code, so I didn't waste anymore time on it.

I am assuming you wanted to use JPlayer to play your mp3 in a customizaible player. If this is the case, there are alternitives. One example is http://www.staticplayer.com/. You can create a custom player. This enables you to change every aspect of the Flash Mp3 Player from the play button to the display text, and everything in between. Click on the site link and use the controls on the right to adjust the settings of the player to make the mp3 player look any way you want.

Static player is also only about 3kb, making it EXTREMELY light weight. In other words, it will likely be the first thing to load on your website before anything else because it's so small. And it's free.

Here is an example of the player using the mp3 song in your code above. Just copy and paste this code in the Layout section of Blogger by clicking on "Add a Gadget" and selecting "HTML/ Javascript":

```
    <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,28,0" width="187" height="35">

    <param name="movie" value="http://www.staticplayer.com/Flash/chameleon.swf" />

    <param name="AllowScriptAccess" value="always" /><param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="scale" value="noscale" /><param name="salign" value="lt" /><param name="wmode" value="transparent" />

    <param name="flashvars" value="mp3_url=http://files.mboxdrive.com/1296462407/Lutan Fyah - Badmind.mp3&autoplay=no&bg_type=none&bg_width=187&bg_height=35&bg_alpha=100&bg_color=0x000000&bg_image=http://www.staticplayer.com/images/chameleon/default.gif&border_type=ellipse&border_color=0xAAAAAA&border_width=1&border_alpha=100&border_ellipse=1&play_color=0xEDD900&play_width=25&play_height=25&play_x=5&play_y=5&show_bar=yes&playbar_color=0xEDD900&load_color=0x404040&load_width=145&load_height=5&load_x=35&load_y=20&show_text=yes&text_size=10&text_color=0xFFFFFF&text_x=32&text_y=5&text_idle=Lutan Fyah - Badmind" />

    <embed src="http://www.staticplayer.com/Flash/chameleon.swf" allowscriptaccess="always" quality="high" scale="noscale" salign="lt" wmode="transparent" flashvars="mp3_url=http://files.mboxdrive.com/1296462407/Lutan Fyah - Badmind.mp3&autoplay=no&bg_type=none&bg_width=187&bg_height=35&bg_alpha=100&bg_color=0x000000&bg_image=http://www.staticplayer.com/images/chameleon/default.gif&border_type=ellipse&border_color=0xAAAAAA&border_width=1&border_alpha=100&border_ellipse=1&play_color=0xEDD900&play_width=25&play_height=25&play_x=5&play_y=5&show_bar=yes&playbar_color=0xEDD900&load_color=0x404040&load_width=145&load_height=5&load_x=35&load_y=20&show_text=yes&text_size=10&text_color=0xFFFFFF&text_x=32&text_y=5&text_idle=Lutan Fyah - Badmind" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="188" height="36"></embed></object>
```

It's easy to change the look and style of the player just by looking at the code, but if you run into problems, use their helpful site to make the player customizations that you want: http://www.staticplayer.com/